# Drupal 7 localhost is shortening css strings

Tags: 7, theming

My local copy of a Drupal 7.19 site has been cutting the css strings and I cannot figure it out.  I have checked my .info file, settings file and tried disabling modules, all to no avail.  It continues to render css like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/rwr/" media="all">
```

Where is should be

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/rwr/sites/all/[themename]/css/global.base.css" media="all">
```

My remote site is generating @import calls to the css, but my localhost is not.

Feel free to link me to an existing solution for this.  I have been googling and reading for hours, but I cannot find a solution.  Thank you!

Comment: Let me see your `.info ` file

Comment: Here's a link to the file on Dropbox.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24041302/glrwr01.info

Comment: I still can't get this to work.  This is the style sheet call in my .info file:  stylesheets[all][] = js/select2/select2.css
  stylesheets[screen][] = css/global.base.css
  stylesheets[screen][] = css/global.styles.css
  stylesheets[screen][] = css/rwr.css

Answer (score 0):

same issue, to me helps:

visit: admin/config/development/performance

turn on "CACHING" for:
 Cache pages for anonymous users

turn off all "BANDWIDTH OPTIMIZATION" 
 Compress cached pages.
 Aggregate and compress CSS files.
 Aggregate JavaScript files.

Then Clear all cahces

That fix my issue with css ;)

Comment: Cool, thanks!  I'll give it a shot.  I kind of gave up on this, but I'll dive back in when I have a second.  Thanks!!